# Is there a way to specify intermediates_dir for the Knit button in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I have a .Rmd file (say it's called "file.Rmd") that I would like to knit into a pdf by pressing the "Knit" button in RStudio. However, it yields an error because I can't figure out how to specify a value for `intermediates_dir` in the `render` function (for some reason I need to do this in the C drive).

Note that this works fine:

`rmarkdown::render(file.Rmd, intermediates_dir = "C:/")`

Is there a way to tell RStudio to knit using `intermediates_dir = "C:/")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom knitting function in the `knit` field in the YAML frontmatter, e.g.,

```
---
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
    rmarkdown::render(inputFile, intermediates_dir = "C:/")
  })
---
```

Then when you press the Knit button in RStudio, this custom function will be called to render your Rmd document. For more info, see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-knit.html.

Comment: Wow, great! Didn´t know that!

Comment: Oh, what a nice and simple solution! Thank you! For some bizarre reason (to me, anyway) adding that YAML line crashes the knitr call if the code contains a call of the `source` function -- the document knits nicely when that `source` call is removed! Cool beans. Much appreciated.